# Рисование прямых с использованием С++

Tags: графика

Нужно реализовать алгоритм Брезенхема для прямой и окружности, но без использования OpenGL. 
Немного запутался в том, как же это сделать. Рисовать в консоле не подойдет, так как я понимаю, не можно реализовать рисование расстровым подходом в самой консоле, нужно какое-то окно (хотя консоль так же есть окном). 
А как тогда можно реализовать это рисование? Использования `Win32 API`, это подходящий вариант?

Comment: Если используется Borland C++ 3.1, то рисовать в нём можно. Какой вообще компилятор?

Comment: @Qwertiy Каких-то требований к компилятору не указано, думаю это не играет роли

Comment: Заведите прямоугольную матрицу `N x M` и считайте, что это Ваш холст, а элементы - пиксели.

Comment: @Igor как один из вариантов подходит, но все же лучше не изобретать здесь велосипед)

Comment: Что за хамский комментарий? Это точный и правильный ответ на Ваш вопрос в том виде, в котором Вы его задали.

Comment: @Igor, вообще-то не вижу ничего хамского.

Comment: @Igor почему хамский? Мне просто нужно понять или `Win32` подходящий вариант для этого рисования или есть вариант проще или лучше? Мне Ваш вариант нравится, но не очень подходит так как нужно еще и правильно работать с матрицей, в то время как было желательно делегировать эту работу на другие библиотеки, а основной уклон сделать на сам алгоритм. Не было намерений Вас задеть ответом или обидеть.

Comment: Объясните, какова конечная цель этого действа (не очень понятно `желательно делегировать эту работу на другие библиотеки,`)

Comment: @MBo ну к примеру, мы же не считаем вручную пиксели в шейдерах. за это отвечает другие библиотеки вне скоупа нашего кода в самих шейдерах